# Google Earth .amd64 14.04 Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, google-earth

I want to get Google Earth, and whenever I try an installer it just says

```
    The setup program seems to have failed on amd64.

    Fatal error, installer failed to run at all!
```

I'm using a link from [Google Earth Pro download.](http://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html)

How do I solve this without changing my computer or operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth#Recommended_installation_methods

> **Note to 64bit users**: The 64bit debian package depends on ia32-libs which is deprecated and no longer available as of 13.10 Saucy. Use the
>   32bit package and multiarch-support.

Try to install 32bit package. You should use this if installing the 32bit package

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 \
libglu1-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libxext6:i386 \
libxrender1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 lsb-core
```